# GitLab variables are not really private, are they?

Tags: ssh, gitlab, environment-variables, cicd

I am an experienced CI&CD engineer coming from a Configuration Management expertise in processes, methods and tools.
However, I am not so experienced in using GitLab CI/CD for automation. I have plenty experience using Jenkins though, and I find myself a bit confused as there really does not seem to be truly user-private variables for GitLab pipeline setups

Am I right?
All the variables I can manage to see, as administrator, are visible to all other administrators.
Therefore I am quite reluctant to execute a solution such as proposed in https://gitlab.com/gitlab-examples/ssh-private-key/-/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml

Am I missing something, or will not the SSH_PRIVATE_KEY be accessible to all administrators in our setup?

Masking only goes as far as to block visibility in logs, which is fine and all, but I do not want anyone to be able to access the variable content unless thet login with the given account for which a private ssh-key is used.
Hardly the visibility I want to ensure for an account that has ssh-access to ALL environment hosts from dev and test to QA and PROD... :7

Answer (score 0):

Your assessments are correct: users with sufficient access (especially administrators) can reveal the values of variables set in CI/CD settings.

To meet your requirements and for more advanced control of secret access, consider using the [Vault integration](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/authenticating-with-hashicorp-vault/) with user-based claim boundaries. Or, similarly, you can use OpenID connect claims to [connect to cloud providers](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/cloud_services/index.html) that can in turn be used to retrieve secrets stored with your cloud provider (e.g. AWS Secrets Manager)